# WPF error 'calling thread cannot access this object' trying to play sounds in c# class

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

In my `class` `Clicker.cs`, I am attempting to play a sound using a `MediaPlayer`. However, whenever I call the method to toggle off the `MediaPlayer`, I get the error that the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. This code works fine in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, but it does not work in `Clicker.cs`. I found similar problems online, and the fix was to use `Dispatcher.Invoke()`. However, this did not work. The error specifically happens when StopSoundClicker() is called. My code is below:

```cs
private static MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
private static bool isPlaying = false;

public Clicker(KeyInfo k)
{
    player.Open(new Uri(@"C:\Users\chris\Downloads\Recording2.wav"));
    player.MediaEnded += Loop;
}

private void StartSoundClicker()
{
    player.Play();
    isPlaying = true;
}

private static void Loop(object? sender, EventArgs? e)
{
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        if (isPlaying)
        player.Play();
    });
}

private async void StopSoundClicker()
{
    await Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(70);
        player.Stop();
        isPlaying = false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error occurs when you're calling `.Dispatcher` on MainWindow instnace from background thread.

Replace

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher
```

With

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher
```

I think this variant is what `StopSoundClicker` should be!

```
private async Task StopSoundClicker()
{
    await Task.Delay(70);
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        player.Stop();
        isPlaying = false;
    });
}
```

Comment: This is a poor explanation. Mainwindow is a window and hence ui, with thread affinity. Referencing any property of ui from a non ui thread is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should use the `Dispatcher` of the element you are accessing.
Of course, this will almost always be `Application.Current.Dispatcher`.
But in some cases this may not be the case.
And in CodeBehind, you can simply use `Dispatcher` - this is a property of the Window. And all its elements have the same `Dispatcher`.

But in your task, I don't see the need to use it at all - Clickers are always called on the UI thread.

In my opinion, this code should work:

```cs
private async void StopSoundClickerAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   await Task.Delay(70);

   player.Stop();
   isPlaying = false;
}
```